# Routed Defined But It Says 404 Not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

This is my Routes

```
Route::get("experience",[experienceController::class,'experience'])->name('experience');
Route::get("add_experience",[experienceController::class,'add_experience'])->name('add_experience');
Route::post("store_experience",[experienceController::class,'store_experience'])->name('store_experience');
Route::get("all_experience",[experienceController::class,'all_experience'])->name('all_experience');
Route::get('view/experience/{id}',[experienceController::class,'view_experience']);
Route::get('delete_experience/{id}',[experienceController::class,'delete_experience']);
Route::get('edit_experience/{id}',[experienceController::class,'delete_experience']);
```

**This is my URLS:**

```
<td>
  <a href="{{URL::to('edit_experience'.$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Edit</a>
  <a href="{{URL::to('delete_experience'.$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
  <a href="{{URL::to('view_experience/'.$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">View</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Missing some `/` in your urls

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
<td>
  <a href="{{URL::to('edit_experience/'.$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Edit</a>
  <a href="{{URL::to('delete_experience/'.$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
  <a href="{{URL::to('view_experience/'.$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">View</a>
</td>
```

And, in your case i can see that you have a full CRUD stracture, so you might consider using the resource route [(see laravel documentation)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers), and will be created the index, show, create, store, edite, update and destroy routes, all with names.

On the other side, i sugest using the route('name') function, that i think is better, for you not to be modifying all your website in case of a route change.

Good Luck, Hernán.